# import module from node js into react using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, module, axios

so I'm trying to export this from node js

```
const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {//you need to export it into axios in the home file
  if(req.session.isAuth) {
    next();
  }else{
    console.log("you are not authenticated")
  }
}
```

into my react file, I heard that I would need to use Axios, does anyone have an idea on how I would do this with Axios